How to use class selectors when using Angular directives
I'm currently trying to recreate the logic Angular uses for Angular Material Cards. Functionality wise it's working for me, but my styling is not being applied when I try to switch to class selectors instead of css selectors. Here's some code of my use case:
card.component.ts
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  Directive,
  HostBinding,
  ViewEncapsulation,
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: `[card-header], [cardHeader]`,
  host: { class: 'card-header' },
})
export class CardHeader {}

@Directive({
  selector: `[card-content], [cardContent]`,
  host: { class: 'card-content' },
})
export class CardContent {}

@Directive({
  selector: `[card-footer], [cardFooter]`,
  host: { class: 'card-footer' },
})
export class CardFooter {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrl: './card.component.scss',
  host: {
    class: 'app-card',
  },
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class CardComponent {}

card.component.html
<ng-content></ng-content>

card.component.scss
app-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  padding-top: 14px;
}

.card-header {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.card-content {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 16px;
}

.card-footer {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 16px 0px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #444;
}

app.component.ts
<app-card>
  <div card-header>Header Content</div>
  <div card-content>Main Content</div>
  <div card-footer>Footer Content</div>
</app-card>

The app-card styling does get applied, not the card-header, card-content and card-footer. I can find the attributes in the DOM on the element, no classes though. My goal is to get the same functionality as Angular Material Card, just with my own styling and as my own component.

What happens if you omit encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None or change its value?

@BennyHalperin it loses the styling for app-card

I tried writing an example and it worked：StackBlitz
My guess is that the reason it doesn't work is because: you are using a standalone component, but the directive is not standalone directive.
So, the directive is not actually executed. <div card-header>Header Content</div> will remain as is.

(facepalm) I forgot to import the directive in the component where it's used. Thank you
